# Accessing fixture data inside `it` "a test case"

Tags: cypress, fixtures

How can I access the following fixtures inside an `it` block:

`users.json`

```
{
"users": [
    {
        "first_name": "Fadi",
        "last_name": "Salam", 
        "work_email": "fadi.salam@bayzat.com"
    },
    {
        "first_name": "Maha",
        "last_name": "Black", 
        "work_email": "maha.black@bazyat.com"
    }
  ] 
}
```

My cypress **related** function code:

```
descibe('test', () => {
    beforeEach(function(){
    cy.restoreToken()
    cy.fixture('users.json').as('users')
    })

    it('Add an Employee', function() {
           cy.get('@users').then((users) => {
            const user_1 = users[0]
            cy.add_employee(user_1.first_name, user_1.last_name, user_1.work_email)
        }
    )}
})
```

I am unable to access first_name, ... etc

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've changed a few typos in your code and make it work.

In your users.json file 'first_name' is nested under 'users'.

You can use 
users.users[0].first_name  to access first_name. Sample code below,

```
cy.get('@users').then((users) => {
            console.log(users.users[0].first_name);
        })
```

The console would print 'Fadi' in your case.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access this fixure in all contexts and it blocks, you can do the following:

```
const USERS;

before (() => {
  cy.fixture('users.json').then(($users) => USERS = $users);
}
```

Then you access the const.

```
cy.getUserName().should('have.text', USERS[0].first_name);
```